# Issue whith transparent textures when loading a prefab in Unity

Tags: unity, textures, materials

I'm trying to implement Asset Bundles in my Unity game.

I used to instantiate a prefab with `Instantiate<GameObject>(gameRootPrefab)`, which worked fine.

Now this prefab is in a Asset Bundle, so I'm loading this Asset Bundle with `AssetBundle.LoadFromFile()`, and get the prefab to instantiate with `LoadAsset<GameObject>(prefabName)`. I instantiate the prefab the same way as before.

However, I'm now getting an issue with some transparent textures:

[image]

This white square is supposed to be a texture with some transparent parts.
I tried tweaking the material and the texture associated to this GameObject, but I'm still getting the same result. Here's the material and texture:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the material and texture getting loaded (or need to be) from the asset bundle too?

Comment: I put a prefab holding a reference to that material into the asset bundle, so yes I guess.

Comment: I'm honestly not show how that works, you *may* have to load the texture separately. Or the material. I don't know. But that's what is looking like is happening.

Comment: did you get solution on this i have same problem.

Comment: @eswarkumar Given the state of this question, if you end up creating a new question about this, we'll close this one as a duplicate of your own, new question.